# How to properly use DBpedia for SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am currently learning about SPARQL, and I'd like to use DBpedia SPARQL endpoint.
Here is the endpoint : https://dbpedia.org/sparql

And here is a link toward DBpedia ontology : https://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/ontology

***My goal is to find all the Nobel Prize scientist in the field of Physics only, and order them by their age.***

However, I am not yet used to finding the information I want... For example, I found here http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/ some interesting classes such as **Scientist** or **NobelPrize** and also interesting properties like **award**, but they don't give me any result on this simple query :

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?scientist
WHERE {
?scientist a dbpedia-owl:Scientist .
?scientist dbpprop:award dbpedia-owl:NobelPrize .
?scientist dbpprop:age ?age
}
ORDER BY ?age
```

I am also unable to find a proper way to specifically look for Physic Nobel Prize...

Can someone help me through this query ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Check for example Albert Einstein how the data is modeled: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Einstein - he has an award in `Nobel_Prize_in_Physics`, but for whatever reason, this is not an instance of `NobelPrize` nor a subclass. You can try a pattern like `?scientist dbpedia-owl:award ?award . ?award dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Nobel_Prize> .`

Comment: the other issue is 1) you used a variable `?w`, that isn't connected to anything. Not sure why you did this. 2) there is no property `age`, would also be rather odd given that this value would have to be updated every year. You should use the `birthDate` property instead. Indeed, you could try to compute the age, there is a `now()` function - but it's not trivial with all the ifs and obviously, for dead people it doesn't make sense and you should handle this

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I was struggling too much by looking at some properties of the class NobelPrize while Nobel_Prize_in_Physics was simply an instance of the class Award. 
Can you please tell me where you found the data instance Albert Einstein ? I'm a bit confused on the organization of everything, I was more used to simpler rdfs/rdf file...

My final query is :

SELECT ?scientist ?birth
WHERE {
?scientist a dbpedia-owl:Scientist .
?scientist dbpedia-owl:award dbpedia:Nobel_Prize_in_Physics .
?scientist dbo:birthDate ?birth
}
ORDER BY ?birth

Comment: I found it by simply running your query with just the first triple pattern, i.e. `SELECT ?scientist
WHERE {
?scientist a dbpedia-owl:Scientist .}` - indeed, if your know some examples, in your case scientist with Nobel Prize, just use a search engine like google for it, i.e. *"Albert Einstein + DBedia"*

Comment: BUT: now your query is too specific, it just returns winners of the `Nobel_Prize_in_Physics` - that's not what you want. Why didn't you use the suggestion of my first comment?